# How can I retrieve a list of companies that deal in a specific field?

Tags: data-request, companies

I would like to find a list of company that deal with a specific sector of industry. I don't know how I can retrieve these data, I know that probably there is a list in Chambers of Commerce but I know that it could be very expensive.

In my specific case I am looking for the companies that deals with analytical chemistry, quality control in Aberdeen in Scotland. Have you any idea about how can I do that?

Comment: If you're looking for companies based on broad categorizations, D&B (http://www.dnb.com/) or a lead-gen company such as salesgenie.com is likely a good place to start. In your case, with a specific industry and country/locale, I would look for open data around licensing/permits. Have you thought about reaching out to these folks at http://www.sdi.co.uk/invest/sectors/chemical-sciences ?

Comment: Another non-open data source would be the good 'ol yellow book. For example:  http://www.yell.com/s/chemical-aberdeen.html. They might have a business data product or scraping the data is always an option.

Comment: @MarkSilverberg thanks the second link is useful but I thought that maybe there was another way to do that, because I don't see many of the companies that I have already found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a [list of UK registered limited companies](http://download.companieshouse.gov.uk/en_output.html) from Companies House that also contains the [SIC Codes](http://www.companieshouse.gov.uk/infoAndGuide/sic/sic2007.shtml) for each company.

These aren't always that informative, but they provide a starting point?